# Why am I getting an Undifined Index error in my php code?

Tags: php

I'm trying to modify a tutorial to suit my needs but I hit a block when I get an error that says the following:

```
 ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\someDirectory\includes\validation_functions.php on line 21

 Call Stack
 #  Time    Memory  Function    Location
 1  0.0028  259080  {main}( )   ..\newUser.php:0
 2  0.0238  350528  validate_presences( )   ..\newUser.php:16
```

My includes look like this:

```
 <?php 
 require_once("/includes/session.php");
 require_once("includes/db_connection.php");
 require_once("includes/functions.php");
 require_once("includes/validation_functions.php");
 ?>
```

and I've created an array to send as required fields from line 16 like this:

```
   // validations
   $required_fields = array("firstName", "lastName", "email", "username", "passward");
   validate_presences($required_fields);
```

and in the validation_functions.php file I have:

```
 function has_presence($value) {
return isset($value) && $value !== "";
  }
  function validate_presences($required_fields) {
   global $errors;
   foreach($required_fields as $field) {
          $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
      if (!has_presence($value)) {
    $errors[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " can't be blank";
     }
     }
 }
```

..I saw similar blocks of code on this forum with solutions but mine must have something to do with the array.  Can you please help me find why I'm getting the Undifined index error?

Thanks for any help!

PS. Line 21: $value =trim($_POST[$field]);

Comment: We would need to see the entirety of the file "validation_functions.php" where the error is happening.

Comment: `username` doesn't exist as an entry in `$_POST`.... you're referencing it in the `trim()` statement before calling `has_presence()` to actually test that it exists

Comment: I think since the only line that could produce the error is: `$value = trim($_POST[$field]);` change it to this: `$value = (!empty($_POST[$field]) ? trim($_POST[$field]): "");` Does that do the trick for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the `trim($_POST[$field])` inside your `function has_presence($value)`

```
function has_presence($field) {
    return isset($_POST[$field]) && trim($_POST[$field]) !== "";
}
function validate_presences($required_fields) {
    global $errors;
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {
        if (!has_presence($field)) {
            $errors[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " can't be blank";
        }
    }
}
```

Your error message is telling you that `$_POST['username']` is not set, which means you are missing a `<input name="username"` in your form.

Comment: Putting the trim in the has_presence didn't work...same error.

Comment: Yep.  field names on the form did not match with those in the function.  Thanks